# PHP + MySql: a particular DELETE function

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have a table with all the product's info.

**PRODUCT TABLE**

produc_id
product_name
img1
img2
img3

I created a page to update the product's info. My problem is how to manage the images. In the variables img1, img2 and img3 I saved the path of the images. Now i would like to delete that record with a link in the update.php page.

I tried something like this:

```
<a href="delete_img.php?id=<?php echo $img1; ?>&product_id=<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
```

the delete_img.php page is:

```
<?php
include '../asset/inc/auth.inc.php';
include '../asset/inc/db.inc.php';

$db = mysql_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD) or 
    die ('Unable to connect. Check your connection parameters.');
mysql_select_db(MYSQL_DB, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

    $img1 = (isset($_GET['img1'])) ? $_GET['img1'] : 0;
    $product_id = (isset($_GET['product_id'])) ? $_GET['product_id'] : 0;

    $query = 'UPDATE product SET img1=NULL WHERE product_id = ' . $product_id;
    // invio la query
    $result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    die("Errore nella query $query: " . mysql_error());
}

// close
mysql_close();

header('Refresh: 0; URL=update_immobile.php?id=' . $immobile_id . '');
?>
```

It works fine, but just for the single variable **img1**. For the second image, if I want to delete it i need another delete_img.php script (delete_img2.php) and so on.

Question: how can I optimize this 'function'?

Comment: Store your data in a normalized form with one image per product per row, in a separate table `ProductImages`.

Comment: If you continue with this script I would use 3 links one for every picture. After you click on a link I would go to delete_IMG.php script. In this script I would do a if then statement. so if 1the delete picture one.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with as many image columns you have (not tested, but you get the idea):

```
<?php
include '../asset/inc/auth.inc.php';
include '../asset/inc/db.inc.php';

$db = mysql_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD) or 
    die ('Unable to connect. Check your connection parameters.');
mysql_select_db(MYSQL_DB, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

    $img = (isset($_GET['img1']) && in_array(key($_GET['img1'], array('img1', 'img2', 'img3')))) ? key($_GET['img1']) : 0;
    $product_id = (isset($_GET['product_id'])) ? (int)$_GET['product_id'] : 0;

    if ($img !== 0) {
        $query = 'UPDATE product SET ' . $img . '=NULL WHERE product_id = ' . $product_id;
        // invio la query
        $result = mysql_query($query);
    }

if (!$result) {
    die("Errore nella query $query: " . mysql_error());
}

// close
mysql_close();

header('Refresh: 0; URL=update_immobile.php?id=' . $immobile_id . '');
?>
```

**Some notes:**
* don't forget to validate user input (I made some small tweaks to the code)
* always use [exit](http://php.net/exit) or [die](http://php.net/die) after sending a redirect header, otherwise anyone could access your admin area with no username/password required

Comment: Hello @machineaddict and thanks for the advise. Unfortunately, the function does not work.

Comment: @user3037382: from this answer you should have taken the idea. of course the script might not work, I didn't tested it.

Comment: Yes, thanks to your suggestion I solved with a similar script.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize this function in a lot of different ways. In the $imgid could be the ID of the image stored (1, 2 or 3), therefore the HTML code would look as followed:

```
<a href="delete_img.php?id=<?=$imgid?>&product_id=<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
```

With this information submitted you can easily alter your MySQL query in the PHP code.

```
switch($_GET["id"]) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
         $field = "img" . $_GET["id"] ;
         break ;
    default:
         $field = "" ;
}

if($table!="") {
    $query = "UPDATE product SET $field=NULL WHERE product_id = $product_id";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
}
```

More suitable would be, if you would create two more tables:

1. a table which stores the image + path
2. an intermediary table which links the image to a product

This way a product can store more than only three images and multiple products can have the same image. Also every image gets a unique ID to delete it (which would make your problem easier to solve).

Comment: Thanks @efux but I'm not a senior developer and this maybe could complicate my app. Best regards

Answer (score -1):

```
$img1 = (isset($_GET['img1'])) ? $_GET['img1'] : 0;
$img2 = (isset($_GET['img2'])) ? $_GET['img2'] : 0;
$img3 = (isset($_GET['img3'])) ? $_GET['img3'] : 0;

$query = 'UPDATE product SET if($img1==0) img1=NULL' ;
$query .= 'if($img2==0) ,img2=NULL' ;
$query .= 'if($img3==0) ,img3=NULL' ;
$query .= 'WHERE product_id = ' . $product_id'

$result = mysql_query($query);

It is simply concatenation of query with if condition.
```

Comment: its just a way for the same not correct code. he can use query concate like this for single query and update the table